# Button under a couple of Textviews

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-button

I'm doing something quite similar to the tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive.

I now want to put a button at the bottom. Then click the button and do something with the selected Values.

I understand, that I need some new layout, because adding the button to the existing one would just add a button to every textview. But I cant figure out how to do it.

Some help would be very nice. Thanks in advance. :)

Edit: That's my layout at the moment.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="30px" >
    </TextView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px" >
    </CheckBox>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This creates something that looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN8Dl.png

My adapter looks like this:

```
public class AttributeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Attribute> {

    private final List<Attribute> list;
    private final Activity context;

    public AttributeAdapter(Activity context, List<Attribute> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_select_attributes, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView text;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_select_attributes, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
            viewHolder.checkbox
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                boolean isChecked) {
                            Attribute element = (Attribute) viewHolder.checkbox
                                    .getTag();
                            element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                        }
                    });
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName() + "  " + list.get(position).getType());
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        return view;
    }
```

Now i want a button at the bottom to continue with the selected values.

Comment: Please try to include your actual code in questions

Comment: I am not getting what are you trying to do..

Comment: I can not understand your question! what have you tried so far? include you code please and then we might be able to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new layout or xml file named `activity_base` and add following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BaseActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
         >

    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

in your `ListActivity` in the `Oncreate` add `setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);`
This should do the job.

Comment: hmm... that would do the job for a ListView i guess? I got a couple of TextViews. I edited my post for more informations. Perhaps your provided code works, but i dont know how i can use it. :)

Comment: according to the tutorial you must have 1 `ListActivity` named as `MyList` right? in the `MyList` `onCreate` add `setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);` and make another layout named `acitivty_base` with the given code above. The layout you created is a row and `ArrayAdapter` is replicating it, you need another layout to create a button at bottom just once thats something `activity_base` is doing. Try it.